# Skeleton moved between Object Mode and Edit Mode

Tags: rigging

I have a problem to solve. I have a mesh of a character that I created for a game, using Blender 2.80.75. I then found a skeleton animation on cgspeed.com which is fine for my case. The problem I encountered is the position of the skeleton that changes when I am in Edit Mode compared to that in Object Mode. They are not the same. In particular in Object Mode the skeleton has its feet placed on the X-Y plane, while in Edit Mode it slides lower. It also changes the pose. How should I do it ?

[image: Skelethon in Object Mode]

[image: Skelethon in Edit Mode]

Comment: In Edit Mode you always see the rest pose. If you apply this as the rest pose in Pose Mode (ctrl+A) it will ruin the animation. So the best what you can do is duplicating the skeleton, apply the T-pose as the rest pose on the new one, create the armature deform, recreate the base pose, apply the armature modifier, then assign the mesh to the original skeleton. But did you try mixamo.com? It rigs your mesh automatically and offers a lot of free animation.

Comment: Yes, I know Mixamo.com but it doesn't have the animation I need, that is, the character has to bend over his legs to pick up an object.